# Dynamically add build flavor from within a custom Gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I'm writing a custom Gradle plugin which will add one or more tasks to an Android project. One of the tasks needs to add an 'ad hoc' build flavor to the list of existing build flavors already defined by the Android project.

I've tried altering one of the existing build flavors by changing the name as shown by the following code:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {
        ProductFlavor adHocFlavor = target.android.productFlavors.first()
        adHocFlavor.name = 'adHoc'
        target.android.productFlavors.add(adHocFlavor)
    }

}
```

The problem here is that all build flavors in `target.android.productFlavors` are read-only at this point and throws the following error:

`Cannot set the value of read-only property 'name' for ProductFlavor_Decorated`

Does anyone have any idea how I can dynamically add a build flavor from within the plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
@Override
void apply(Project target) {
    target.android.productFlavors.create("name")    
}
```

`productFlavors` is an instance of `NamedDomainObjectContainer`.

From [docs of NamedDomainObjectContainer.create()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html#create(java.lang.String)):

> Creates a new item with the given name, adding it to this container.

Thus, this will create a `ProductFlavor` with provided name and it to `productFlavors`.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! However, when I print all build variants afterwards there seems to be none for the product flavor: adHocDebug and adHocRelease

Comment: When do you print? Does your printing task `dependsOn` your plugin's task?

Comment: `ProductFlavor adHocFlavor = target.android.productFlavors.create('adHoc')
            adHocFlavor.setVersionCode(1)
            adHocFlavor.setVersionName('1.0.0')
            target.android.applicationVariants.all { ApplicationVariant variant ->
                println(variant.getName())
            }`

Right after adding the ad hoc build flavor I print the variants, I'm not that familiar with the `dependsOn` task x.

Comment: I created a new empty project and added the plugin. I can see `nameDebug` and `nameRelease` in the gradle output. See `build.gradle` [here](https://pastebin.com/AR5vnVdP).

Comment: Ok, I can see then now as well. They just don't register if I run the same code from a separate task I register from within the plugin, but that was not part of the question so I'll happily accept your anwser :)